# Call CollectionViewCell item from IBAction

Tags: ios, nsindexpath, collectionview

I would like to add actions to a `button` in a `toolbar` I added to a `collectionView`.

The `toolbar` has 4 share buttons but some reason, I'm not able to call the `collectionView` items properly.

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    [_collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]];
    NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [_collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    NSMutableArray *selectedTexts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexPaths) {
        NSArray *section = videoArray[indexPath.section];
        NSString *text = section[indexPath.row];
        [selectedTexts addObject:text];   
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
            composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:text];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", text);
    }
    // NSLog(@"The share works fine");
}
```

This returns an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: i did not understand you completely... why are you inserting a new item at the beginning? (`insertItemsAtIndexPaths`)

Comment: @AndreSlotta Thank you for replying. I thought it made sense but since it doesn't work, it doesn't. With tableview, I usually do     NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tablename indexPathForSelectedRow];
        
        
        int row = [myIndexPath row];
        NSString *title = [iamarray objectAtIndex:row]; and it works. I guess my question is what is the collectionview alternative?!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `-insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` you should take care about `dataSource` methods as well because `UICollectionView` asks them again about updated items. In your case you don't return proper numbers of updated items count in section 0 and that leads to the error you get.

Usually you have some source of your `UICollectionView` and you should update it as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your property which contains your items. Check `numberOfRowsInSection:` method

EDIT:
To share the text of the appropriate collection view cells you no need to insert any cells into existing collection view. try this code

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [_collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    NSMutableArray *selectedTexts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexPaths) {
        NSArray *section = videoArray[indexPath.section];
        NSString *text = section[indexPath.row];
        [selectedTexts addObject:text];
    }

    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                           composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    NSString *textToShare = [selectedTexts componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:textToShare];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", textToShare);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, could you please tell me how to go about this?!

Comment: As far as I understand the idea is to share the text of the selected collection view cells?

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Tried. It returns nothing :(

Comment: Make sure that collection view properties allowsMultipleSelection and allowsSelection are both set to YES. Then under debug mode check that variables selectedIndexPaths and selectedTexts are not nil and has at least one value.

Comment: Still confused :( I tried this: 
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"%@", button);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSString *imagePath = [videoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
    
    NSDictionary *dates = [videoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString *tweet = [dates valueForKeyPath:@"date"];
    NSLog(@"Tweet Date named: %@ at row %ld", tweet, (long)indexPath.row);
    and it crashes still :/